# Caching Health Check Net Core

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

Net Core 2.2 has a support to execute [health checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for published services.
I would like to cache a response of checking.

I see that I can use the [HealthCheckOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.healthchecks.healthcheckoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and set `true` value for the  [AllowCachingResponses](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.healthchecks.healthcheckoptions.allowcachingresponses?view=aspnetcore-2.2) property.

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/api/services/healthCheck",
    new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions()
    {
        AllowCachingResponses = true
    });
```

But I don't understand how I can set the amount time caching. What is the best place to set corresponding HTTP headers(`Cache-Control`, `Expires`, etc.) and how?

My service is published by IIS.

Comment: Setting this to `true` doesn't add any caching headers, based on the docs in the link you provided. It simply doesn't override any you provide as responses: _"If the value is `true` the health check middleware will not modify the cache headers of the response."_

Comment: @John, it is understand, so I ask how I can set a time. Where do I need to set this headers

Comment: [Cache headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Cache_response_directives). You might have to start looking at [customizing the output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-output)

Comment: I know about it, what is the best place to do it in the Web API Net Core?

Comment: why cache your health checks?

Comment: @DanielA.White, The previous version health check(that was not yet in the Net Core 2.2) has this setting. I was not expected that setting was removed. Why do i need it? I have a load balancer. It checks a health of service for every input request. And it is redundantly.

Comment: that sounds like the wrong tool for the job. if the setting isn't there, perhaps the actual request should return an error.

Comment: You want to cache the health check if you accessing something like KeyVault and this endpoint is accessible from the outside. Someone can use it... I'll write something, it shouldn't be hard

Answer (score 1):

The `AllowCachingResponses` option you mention relates only to whether HTTP headers are set by the [HealthCheckMiddleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.healthchecks.healthcheckmiddleware). Typically, intermediate servers, proxies, etc. may cache the result of a GET request and those headers indicate that the server should re-fetch them every time.

However, if your load balancer is using these checks to indicate whether the service should receive more traffic, it is likely not caching the results anyway.

To accomplish what you're looking for, you would need to write additional logic. One approach would be to write a type of `HealthCheckCacher` like the following:

```
public class HealthCheckCacher : IHealthCheck
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    private readonly IHealthCheck _healthCheck;
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeToLive;

    private HealthCheckResult _result;
    private DateTime _lastCheck;

    public static readonly TimeSpan DefaultTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new HealthCheckCacher which will cache the result for the amount of time specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="healthCheck">The underlying health check to perform.</param>
    /// <param name="timeToLive">The amount of time for which the health check should be cached. Defaults to 30 seconds.</param>
    public HealthCheckCacher(IHealthCheck healthCheck, TimeSpan? timeToLive = null)
    {
        _healthCheck = healthCheck;
        _timeToLive = timeToLive ?? DefaultTimeToLive;
    }

    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // you could improve thread concurrency by separating the read/write logic but this would require additional thread safety checks.
        // will throw OperationCanceledException if the token is canceled while we're waiting.
        await _mutex.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            // previous check is cached & not yet expired; just return it
            if (_lastCheck > DateTime.MinValue && DateTime.Now - _lastCheck < _timeToLive)
                return _result;

            // check has not been performed or is expired; run it now & cache the result
            _result = await _healthCheck.CheckHealthAsync(context, cancellationToken);
            _lastCheck = DateTime.Now;

            return _result;
        }
        finally
        {
            _mutex.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you inject this in the healthcheck pipeline? Your HealthCheckCacher needs a IHealthCheck instance

Answer (score 1):

I have a scheduled job inside my APIs which invokes `HealthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync()` and stores the `HealthReport` result. I then just create regular API endpoints which returns this value. Far simpler and doesn't require an artificial wrapper health check.

Edit: As requested, hopefully enough supporting code to demonstrate.

Controller method:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns the last global health check result.
    /// </summary>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/health"), HttpGet]
    public HealthReport Health() => HealthJob.LastReport;
```

And bits of the scheduled job. You will need to register the `BackgroundService` using `AddHostedService<HealthJob>()` on `IServiceCollection`:

```cs
public class HealthJob : BackgroundService
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan CheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    // [snip]

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                LastReport = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync(stoppingToken);
                LastExecution = DateTime.Now;
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // Ignored
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // [snip]
                //
                // TODO assign LastReport to error values
            
            }
            
            await Task.Delay(CheckInterval, stoppingToken);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a great opportunity to provide folks some code...

Comment: I would, except this is for a commercial rather than personal project so am erring on the side of caution.

Comment: I can understand the issue. I have personal experience with the ramifications of sharing code, even when it's trimmed down to the minimum to make a point. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/release-is-not-debug-64bit-optimizations-and-c-method-inlining-in-release-build-call-stacks. This code was cited as a reason for my being let go when I was a contractor 15 years ago.

Comment: Might be a little too late, but I've included enough code to hopefully provide a pointer about my approach.

Comment: I've simplified my controller endpoint in the code above. In reality, I'm including the assembly version, hostname and the last check time in the results, as these are all very useful things to have. The health check job itself is also reporting health metrics to an external system.

Comment: > Might be a little too late
never too late for sharing.